# Match words in file with regex php

Tags: php, regex

I'm new with regex and php. I know this quite simple but i just can't get it. Now, i have file words.txt that contain:

```
happy
sad
laugh
```

I want to find match this sentence with my words.txt:

> I am happy

So far, i've tried this but it doesn't valid because it read as a sentence not words: (not yet implement regex bcs im confused)

```
$input0= "I am happy";
$handle = fopen('words.txt', 'r');
$valid = false; 
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
if (strpos($buffer, $input0) !== false) { // here's the problem
    $valid = TRUE;
    break;
   }      
}
if($valid == TRUE){
//print the matches word
}
fclose($handle);
```

can u help me? :(

Comment: [fread()](http://php.net/fread) or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) the entire file into a variable, then use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: @Zanderwar okkk thank you! I get it with : preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches). Can you help me with the pattern? I was curious;')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your final goal you may not even need regexp here, since you want to match entire word with no variable part.

if you want to have a loop on your keywords a simple str_replace() would do the job to replace the word by an emphasize one for instance, or simple `if (strpos($input0, $word) !== false)` to just check if found in sentence and find position.

But if you want to avoid a loop, **for faster results** and especially if you have many words `preg_match_all()` will do what you need as said by Zanderwar.
Here is an example:

```
$input0= "I am happy but sometimes quite pretty sad. It depends but I prefer to be happy in general.\nMy paragraph also continue on multilines\nend it makes me laugh and rejoy. I am so happy. HAPPY?";
// $contents = file_get_contents('words.txt');
$contents = "happy\nsad\nlaugh";

$words_list = str_replace("\n", '|', $contents);

if (preg_match_all("~($words_list)~si", $input0, $matches))
{
    print_r(array($matches));
    // Do what you want
}
```

The `i` flag match case insensitive if you need.

The `s` flag match on multilines content.

[EDIT] to add more details on regexp

In the pattern you need a delimiter which can be `~` because it is very seldom used in sentences and strings to match so you wont need to escape `/` as when you use `/` delimiter.

also I am joining your words like `~(sad|joy|happy)~` if you want to capture the words. if you don't you need a group like `(?:sad|joy|happy)`

the `|` means or.

You can try to replace regex `~($words_list)~si` by `~(?:$words_list)~si` if you dont need capturing - and you don't - you will then have only one level of captures in $matches array, at position [0] it is always the full match. but here you don't have more complex patterns to match and so no need to capture

Comment: Thank you so much! I learn a lot from your explaination :D these are make sense now, but lil' problem when i change contents with my filename.txt there's no output, am i make a mistake? (I put it in the same dir with my codefile)

Comment: pleasure ;)  Did you update `$contents = file_get_contents('words.txt');` with new file name?

Comment: I already change it to `$contents = file_get_contents('stopwords.txt'); ` that's actually my file name

Comment: try to debug if file exists with `is_file('stopwords.txt')` first, or `scandir();` to make sure your file is found.

Comment: file is exist and already change with words1 |words2 |words3 |etc, hmm maybe the whitespace between words and "OR" affect it?

Comment: In your file you have to do as the beginning one match per line. When you have any doubt of sth, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`!

Comment: I am replacing your keywords with `str_replace("\n", '|', $contents);` so it is expecting line breaks!